# scala hang when run List.par.aggregate

Tags: scala, aggregation

when I try to run the following code in REPL, it hangs. when I remove the parallel 'par', it is able to evaluate. I am totally noob in terms of the scala land. The program is trying to do the count the occurrence. I know there is other way to produce the same values, but I would like know why it doesn't work.

```
val hashMap = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[String, Int]()
val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
s.par.aggregate(hashMap) ( (m, x) => {m.put(x, m.getOrDefault(x, 0) + 1); m}, (x,y) => x)
// the code above hangs
s.aggregate(hashMap) ( (m, x) => {m.put(x, m.getOrDefault(x, 0) + 1); m}, (x,y) => x)
//this works
```

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see the difference between 2nd and 4th last line. Don't I just see it, or did you incidently post 2 times the same line?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me in the IntelliJ scratch-pad but it does hang the REPL. This is unfortunate but not too surprising. Due to the REPL's interactive nature it's not always well suited for asynchronous computations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jwvh. Good to know that is the REPL issue.

Comment: same proble on scala 2.12.10 cli